# CasperJS fill form without form id

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So I got the problem, that I can't fill this form, because there is no ID und with `class=login` he can't find it.
I've tried `sendkeys`, `this.fillSelectors`, `document.querySelector` and `this.fill`....

```
<div id="login_panel">
                <form action="?s=user" method="POST" class="login">
                    <center><input style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:16px;" type="text" class="input" name="userid" onfocus="if(this.value=='User')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='User'" value="User">
                    <input style="margin-top:-2px; margin-left:16px;" type="password" class="input" name="userpass" onfocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" value="Password">
                    <a href="index.php?s=pass_lost">* Passwort vergessen?</a>
                    <input style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:16px;" type="submit" class="bt_enter" value="LOGIN" name="submit"></center>\
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? Using a class selector rather than an ID selector should work just fine with `.fill` and `.fillSelectors`. Are you waiting for the form to load before trying to fill it?

Comment: i wait until some .jpg is loaded.. (it worked one time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wait until some .jpg is loaded.. (it worked one time).

```
casper.then(function() {
 this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
        document.querySelector('input[node-type="userid"]').value = username;
        document.querySelector('input[node-type="userpass"]').value = password;
        document.querySelector('.W_btn_g:eq(1)').click();
        this.click('input[value="LOGIN"]'); 
    }, 'Dantes999', '123456789');
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys('input[name=userid]', 'Dantes999');
    this.sendKeys('input[name=userpass]', '123456789');
    this.click('input[value="LOGIN"]'); 
});
casper.then(function() {
this.fillSelectors('form#login_panel', {
    'input[name=userid]': 'Dantes999',
    'input[name=userpass]': '123456789'
}, true);
});
casper.then(function() {
    this.fill('form[class="login"]', {
          'userid': 'Dantes999',
          'userpass': '123456789'
        }, true);
});
```